# can the sorting from an order by statement be saved explicitly in a table (SQL Server Version 2017)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have this table

```
AGENT_CODE AGENT_NAME      WORKING_AREA                        
---------- ------------- ---------------
A001       Subbarao        Bangalore                           
A002       Mukesh          Mumbai                              
A003       Alex            London
```

Sorting the above table should give me the below result.

```
select * 
from table_name 
order by agent_name;

AGENT_CODE AGENT_NAME      WORKING_AREA                        
---------- ------------- ---------------
A003       Alex             London                           
A002       Mukesh           Mumbai                              
A001       Subbarao         Bangalore
```

Now, I want to keep my table and save the sorted order on the positioned rows permanently onto the same table

Eg: when I run

```
 select * from table_name
```

the results should appear as below without ordering

```
AGENT_CODE AGENT_NAME      WORKING_AREA                        
---------- ------------- ---------------
A003       Alex             London                           
A002       Mukesh           Mumbai                              
A001       Subbarao         Bangalore
```

Comment: Hi interesting, this might be of interest https://sqlworkbooks.com/2018/02/does-a-clustered-index-give-a-default-ordering/

Comment: No - a table by definition is an unordered set. If you need ordered rows, the query that creates those rows must order them. If not, order is undefined and will be based on runtime factors.

Answer (score 1):

> Eg: when i run select * from table_name. The results should appear as below without ordering

No, this is not possible. SQL tables represent *unordered* set of rows. In absence of an explicit `order by` clause in the query, the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes, and the sort is not guaranteed to be consistent over consequent executions of the same query.

So if you want a consistent ordering, *do* use an `order by` clause to your query.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a clustered index on the table ( if there isnt already one). Then your table will be sorted in that order...but it does not guarantee that a select query will return the data in that order. Only by specifying an order by clause will do so.

Why is it not possible to use an order by?